# Python - Plotly - make_subplots - Title Overlap / Move Subplot Titles

Tags: python, plotly

How do I adjust the subplot titles so that they don't overlap with the x-axis?

[image: Plotly Image]

Here is the code for reference:

```py
import math
import pandas as pd
import plotly.subplots as ps
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# create subplots
x_axis_groups = df.groupby("x_axis_group")
fig = ps.make_subplots(
    rows=math.ceil(len(list(x_axis_groups)) / 3),
    cols=3,
    subplot_titles=[name for name, _ in x_axis_groups],
    horizontal_spacing=0.025,
    vertical_spacing=0.1,
)
for i, (_, group) in enumerate(x_axis_groups):
    subfig = go.Heatmap(x=group["x-axis"], y=group["y-axis"], z=group['z'])
    fig.append_trace(subfig, row=i//3+1, col=i%3+1)
fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    title_text='Total PF reads per plate',
    font=dict(size=18),
    xaxis=dict(range=[1, 12], side="top", dtick=1),
    yaxis=dict(autorange="reversed")
)
```

Comment: Set `horizontal_spacing=0.75`

Answer (score 0):

There is an annotation that defines the position of the title for each subplot, so change it: from the information in `fig.layout` you can see the value of `yaxis['domain']`, and adjust it to fit your graph. Also, the vertical spacing is too small, so increase the value. I created a graph similar to yours in my environment and adjusted the following settings

```
fig = make_subplots.make_subplots(
    rows=2,
    cols=3,
    subplot_titles=['7','8','9','10','11','12'],
    horizontal_spacing=0.025,
    vertical_spacing=0.2,
)
...

fig.layout.annotations[0].update(y=1.1)
fig.layout.annotations[1].update(y=1.1)
fig.layout.annotations[2].update(y=1.1)
fig.layout.annotations[3].update(y=0.5)
fig.layout.annotations[4].update(y=0.5)
fig.layout.annotations[5].update(y=0.5)
```

[image]